# Aggregate multiple documents and count sum field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Document:

```
{
  _id: "___"
  finish: false or true
  ... some field..
}
```

Aggregate result:

```
{
  finish: 10,
  non_finish: 3,
  results: [
   docuemnt,
   docuemnt,
   ...
  ]
}
```

Is it possible? I know how can I count `finish`, with condition
but how to aggregate document array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

1. `$set` - Set `finish_count` and `non_finish_count` fields by checking the `finish`, if match then 1, else 0.
2. `$group` - Group by `null`, sum the `finish_count` and `non_finish_count` fields. Add each document into `documents` array.
3. `$unset` - Remove `documents.finish_count` and `documents.non_finish_count`fields.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      finish_count: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "$finish",
              true
            ]
          },
          then: 1,
          else: 0
        }
      },
      non_finish_count: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "$finish",
              false
            ]
          },
          then: 1,
          else: 0
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      finish: {
        $sum: "$finish_count"
      },
      non_finish: {
        $sum: "$non_finish_count"
      },
      documents: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: [
      "documents.finish_count",
      "documents.non_finish_count"
    ]
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (Solution 1)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/o539-vHceZW)

---

**Solution 2**

1. `$group` - Group by `null`, and add each document into the `documents` array.
2. `$set` - Set the fields by counting the size (`$size`) of the array by filtering the document with `finish` (`finish: true`) and `non_finish` (`finish: false`) from the `documents` array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      documents: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      finish: {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$documents",
            cond: {
              $eq: [
                "$$this.finish",
                true
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      non_finish: {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$documents",
            cond: {
              $eq: [
                "$$this.finish",
                false
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground (Solution 2)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/R1544Xrw28M)